# Is there anyway to read the board serial number from a altera Cyclone V FPGA?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

Is there anyway to read the board serial number from a Cyclone V FPGA?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this came in a bit late, but I'm writing for the sake of those still interested.

First, store the board's serial number somewhere, e.g. an EEPROM or a Flash chip on the board. Then, get your FPGA to read that data from the storage device. That's probably the simplest solution I can think of, and works well if you're not concerned about anyone tampering with the storage device (or say, resoldering their own storage device with their own data).